# Error Transaction.new into Rails app trying to import CSV data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I try to import a CSV file into my database in a Rails app. I follow [this gist](https://gist.github.com/arjunvenkat/1115bc41bf395a162084).

Here is my code:

```
# db/seeds.rb
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'siren_db.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
csv.each do |row|
  t = Transaction.new
  t.siren = row['siren']
  t.nom = row['nom']
  t.adresse = row['adresse']
  t.complement_adresse = row['complement_adresse']
  t.pays = row['pays']
  t.region = row['region']
  t.departement = row['departement']
  t.activite = row['activite']
  t.date = row['date']
  t.nb_salaries = row['nb_salaries']
  t.nom = row['nom']
  t.prenom = row['prenom']
  t.civilite = row['civilite']
  t.adr_mail = row['adr_mail']
  t.libele_acti = row['libele_acti']
  t.categorie = row['categorie']
  t.tel= row['tel']
  t.save
  puts "#{t.siren}, #{t.nom} saved"
end

puts "There are now #{Transaction.count} rows in the transactions table"
```

Unfortunately, I have an error but don't know why? (I have the exact same code as the gist) :

> rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant Transaction
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/Public/sites/sirenforest/db/seeds.rb:6:in block
>   in '
>   /Users/nicolasleroux/Public/sites/sirenforest/db/seeds.rb:5:in' Tasks: TOP => db:seed (See full trace by running task
>   with --trace)

### UPDATE

The script works but everything is filled with "nill"... Here are my codes:

```
#db/migrate/create_transaction
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.integer :siren
      t.string :nom_ent
      t.string :adresse
      t.string :complement_adresse
      t.string :pays
      t.string :region
      t.integer :departement
      t.string :activite
      t.integer :date
      t.string :nb_salaries
      t.string :nom
      t.string :prenom
      t.string :civilite
      t.string :adr_mail
      t.string :libele_acti
      t.string :categorie
      t.integer :tel

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

#model transaction
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
end
```

The beginning of the csv file:

```
SIREN;NOM;ADRESSE;COMPLEMENT_ADRESSE;CP_VILLE;PAYS;REGION;DEPARTEMENT;ACTIVITE;DATE;NB_SALARIES;NOM;PRENOM;CIVILITE;ADR_MAIL;LIBELE_ACTI;CATEGORIE;TEL
38713707;SYND COPR DU 6 AU 8 RUE DE CHARONNE 75;6 RUE DE CHARONNE;;75011 PARIS;FRANCE;Île-de-France;75;Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments;2008;1 ou 2 salariés;;;;;Syndicat de copropriété ;PME;
38713707;SYND COPR DU 6 AU 8 RUE DE CHARONNE 75;6 RUE DE CHARONNE;;75011 PARIS;FRANCE;Île-de-France;75;Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments;2008;1 ou 2 salariés;;;;;Syndicat de copropriété ;PME;
38724340;SYND COPR DU 18 BD ARAGO 75013 PARIS;18 BOULEVARD ARAGO;;75013 PARIS;FRANCE;Île-de-France;75;Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments;2008;1 ou 2 salariés;;;;;Syndicat de copropriété ;PME;
```

Comment: Dou you have a model named `Transaction` or you just copied/pasted the gist code without thinking?

Comment: Indeed, sorry I'm just starting with Rails... What should I write into my model for the methods t.name?

Comment: You need to create a model describing the entity this data will fill. I mean, if each line in your CV file represents a customer, for example, you need to create a Custumer model with all the columns you are importing (siren, nom, adresse...).

Comment: Read this before you continue: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 2):

look at the 1. Setup section it says like this:

> Make sure you've created a resource with the appropriate columns to match your seed data. The names don't have to match up.

You must generate Transaction model in your rails application, like this:

```
$ rails generate model Transaction street:text city:string etc...
```

see section 5 on the gist for appropriate columns.

**Update:**
You should've specified delimiter for your CSV file like this:

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1', :col_sep => ';' )
```

also hash key should have been uppercase as in your csv file and you have same column names, should be unique(t.nom). Full code:

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1', :col_sep => ';' )
csv.each do |row|
   t = Transaction.new
   t.siren = row['SIREN']
   t.nom = row['NOM'] # => 2 same columns
   t.adresse = row['ADRESSE']
   t.complement_adresse = row['COMPLEMENT_ADRESSE']
   t.pays = row['PAYS']
   t.region = row['REGION']
   t.departement = row['DEPARTEMENT']
   t.activite = row['ACTIVITE']
   t.date = row['DATE']
   t.nb_salaries = row['NB_SALARIES']
   t.nom = row['NOM'] # => 2 same columns
   t.prenom = row['PRENOM']
   t.civilite = row['CIVILITE']
   t.adr_mail = row['ADR_MAIL']
   t.libele_acti = row['LIBELE_ACTI']
   t.categorie = row['CATEGORIE']
   t.tel= row['TEL']
   t.save
puts "#{t.siren}, #{t.nom} saved"
end

puts "There are now #{Transaction.count} rows in the transactions table"
```

Comment: So I add the columns in the migration file and it should work?

Comment: @AlphaNico yes.

Comment: It works, but I don't know why everything is filled with nill... I have updated my codes in the question

Comment: @AlphaNico did you run `rake db:seed` command after migrating model? this command will run db/seeds.rb file so it will fill your Transactions table according to this db/seeds.rb file

Comment: Yes I did. Actually I am not sure my csv file has the same structure as the gist. I have columns with the different categories and then thousands rows filling these columns. It seems the gist is the opposite : rows with categories and then columns filling them no?

Comment: no gist is getting each row from csv file to Transactions table. Can you show csv file? does it have a header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133214/discussion-between-alphanico-and-tasqyn).

Comment: I just added the beginning of the CSV file to the question ;)